# How to get odd/even value from array and display in table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-table

I have `dataArr = ["1","Maths","2","Science"];` I need to display the values 1,2(S.No) in the first column and the (Subject name) Maths,Science in the second column of a dynamic table.

Any way to do this using jquery/javascript?

Sample table code:

```
 $("#subjectTable").append("<table style='width:100%; height: 4em; border-spacing: 0px;'><tr><td style='width:25%'>"+OddpositionVal+"</td><td style='width:25%'>"+EvenpositionVal+"</td></tr></table>");
```

Comment: Adding a note : How to display the values in the table odd value in the first col,even value in the second col respectively .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dataArr = ["1","Maths","2","Science"];
```

Add a bare bones table to a `div`.

```
$("#subjectTable").append('<table id="table"></table>');
```

For each table row loop over the array in steps of 2 (`i+=2`). `oddPositionVal` is the first element in the step, `evenPositionVal` is the second element.

Build the row HTML and then append it to the table.

```
for (var i = 0, l = dataArr.length; i < l; i+=2) {
  var oddPositionVal = dataArr[i];
  var evenPositionVal = dataArr[i + 1];
  var rowhtml = '<tr><td style="width:25%">' + oddPositionVal + '</td><td style="width:25%">' + evenPositionVal + '</td></tr>';
  $('#table').append(rowhtml);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v6jfnkb5/6/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var dataArr = ["1","Maths","2","Science"];
for (var i=0;i<dataArr.length;i++){
if(i%2==0){
//even index
 console.log("sno="+dataArr[i]);
}
else{
//odd index
  console.log("subject="+dataArr[i]);
}
}
```

**UPDATE:-**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/ygpp6wod/2/)

Comment: If else condition returns 1,2 in first column, blank value in the second column.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/ygpp6wod/1/ heres the fiddle,Its working as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$.each(dataArr,function(index,value){
  if(parseInt(index) % 2 == 0)
  {
     alert(value);
  }
  else
  {
     alert(value);
  }
});
```

Comment: tried it.This is for getting even index value.how to append the values in the table?

Comment: @Sha...strange..after getting answer you posted another requirement...plz post complete question in the starting itself so that we prepare the answer accordingly..now we have to completely redesign our answers...

Comment: Question was the same.I just added the note for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

```
var dataArr = ["1","Maths","2","Science"];

var $table = $("<table style='width:100%; height: 4em; border-spacing: 0px;'>");
var $row = $("<tr>");
$.each(dataArr, function (index, value) {
  $row.append("<td style='width:25%'>" + value + "</td>");
  if (index % 2) {
    $table.append($row);
    $row = $("<tr>");
  }
});

$table.appendTo("#subjectTable");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
var dataArr = ["1","Maths","2","Science"],
    $table = $("<table style='width:100%; height: 4em; border-spacing: 0px;'></table>").appendTo("#subjectTable");

var $tr = null;
$.each(dataArr, function(index) {
    if(index % 2 == 0) {
        $tr = $("<tr>").appendTo($table);
    }
    $tr.append("<td style='width:25%'>" + this + "</td>");
});
```

And here is the working **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/30ub8x62/1/)**